# Show that $(1+x)(1+y)(1+z)\ge 8(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)$.

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis

> If $x>0,y>0,z>0$ and $x+y+z=1$, prove that $$(1+x)(1+y)(1+z)\ge 8(1-x)(1-y)(1-z).$$

Trial: Here  $$(1+x)(1+y)(1+z)\ge 8(1-x)(1-y)(1-z) \\ \implies  (1+x)(1+y)(1+z)\ge 8(y+z)(x+z)(x+y)$$ I am unable to solve the problem. Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$(1+x)(1+y)(1+z) \ge 8(1-x)(1-y)(1-z) \Leftrightarrow $$
$$(2x+y+z)(x+2y+z)(x+y+2z) \ge 8(y+z)(x+z)(x+y)$$

Let $a=x+y, b=x+z, c=y+z$. Then the inequality to prove is

$$(a+b)(a+c)(b+c) \ge 8abc \,,$$

Which follows immediately from AM-GM:

$$a+b \ge 2 \sqrt{ab}$$
$$a+c \ge 2 \sqrt{ac}$$
$$b+c \ge 2 \sqrt{bc}$$

**Simplification** The solution above can be simplified the following way:

By AM-GM

$$2\sqrt{(1-y)(1-z)}\le 1-y+1-z=1+x \,.$$
Similarly
$$2\sqrt{(1-x)(1-z)}\le 1+y \,.$$
$$2\sqrt{(1-x)(1-y)}\le 1+z \,.$$

Answer (score 2):

since 
$$t=(x+y)(y+z)(x+z)\le\left(\dfrac{2(x+y+z)}{3}\right)^3=\dfrac{8}{27}$$

and we
have
$$(1-x)(1-y)\ge 0$$
then
$$(1+x)(1+y)\ge2(x+y)$$

Comment: With the help of your last inequality I get $[(1+x)(1+y)(1+z)]^2\ge 8 (x+y)(x+z)(y+z)$. But I need to show $$(1+x)(1+y)(1+z) \ge 8 (x+y)(x+z)(y+z)$$. How I use your first inequality in solving the problem.