# If $x,y,z>0$ are distinct and $x+y+z=1$ what is the minimum of $\left((1+x)(1+y)(1+z)\right)/\left((1-x)(1-y)(1-z)\right)$?

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, tangent-line-method

If $x,y,z>0$ are not equal and positive and if $x+y+z=1$ the expression

$$\frac{(1+x)(1+y)(1+z)}{(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)}$$

is greater than what quantity?

Comment: you can see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425134/show-that-1x1y1z-ge-81-x1-y1-z/425150#425150

Answer (score 1):

we prove
$$\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}\cdot\dfrac{1+y}{1-y}\cdot\dfrac{1+z}{1-z}\ge 8,x+y+z=1$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow \sum \ln{\left(\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}\right)}\ge 3\ln{2}$$

and  we have
$$\ln{\left(\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}\right)}\ge\dfrac{9}{4}x-\dfrac{3}{4}+\ln{2}$$
poof:let
$$G(x)=\ln{\left(\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}\right)}-\left(\dfrac{9}{4}x-\dfrac{3}{4}+\ln{2}\right)$$
$$\Longrightarrow G'(x)=\dfrac{(3x+1)(3x-1)}{4(1-x^2)}$$
since $0<x<1$, then we have
$$G(x)\ge G(\dfrac{1}{3})=0$$
so
$$\sum \ln{\left(\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}\right)}\ge\dfrac{9}{4}(x+y+z)-\dfrac{3}{4}\cdot 3-3\cdot\ln{2}=3\ln{2}$$
by done!

Answer (score 1):

By AM-GM we obtain:
$$\frac{\prod\limits_{cyc}(1+x)}{\prod\limits_{cyc}(1-x)}=\frac{\prod\limits_{cyc}(2x+y+z)}{\prod\limits_{cyc}(x+y)}=\frac{\prod\limits_{cyc}(x+y+x+z)}{\prod\limits_{cyc}(x+y)}\geq\frac{8\prod\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{(x+y)(x+z)}}{\prod\limits_{cyc}(x+y)}=8.$$
The equality occurs for $x=y=z=\frac{1}{3}$, which says that we got the answer: $8$.