# If a,b,c are positive real numbers such that a + b + c = 1 , then find the minimum value of $\frac{(1+a)(1+c)(1+c)}{(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)}$

Tags: inequality

I tried by solving inequality of numerator and denominator

*Numerator*:

$(1+a)(1+c)(1+c) \leq \frac{(3 + a + b + c)}{3} = \frac{(3 + 1)}{3} = \frac{4}{3}$

*Denominator*:

$(1-a)(1-c)(1-c) \leq \frac{3 - (a + b + c)}{3} = \frac{(3 - 1)}{3} = \frac{2}{3}$

By combining the 2 equations

$\frac{Numerator}{Denominator} \leq \frac{4/3}{2/3} = 2$

But that's not the answer (I know I found max value). Can anyone help me? Is the method I am following can be used in other types of question? Solving Numerator and denominator inequality and than dividing both inequatlity....

ANSWER: 8

Comment: typo in second equation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $x,y,z>0$ are distinct and $x+y+z=1$ what is the minimum of $\left((1+x)(1+y)(1+z)\right)/\left((1-x)(1-y)(1-z)\right)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442136/if-x-y-z0-are-distinct-and-xyz-1-what-is-the-minimum-of-left1x1y)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/425134/42969.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1**  $$\frac{(1+a)(1+c)(1+c)}{(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)}=\frac{(a+b+a+c)(b+c+b+a)(c+a+c+b)}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}$$
Now apply AM-GM in numerator

> use $$(a+b+a+c)(b+c+b+a)(c+a+c+b)$$ $$ \ge 2\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}2\sqrt{(b+c)(b+a)}2\sqrt{(c+a)(c+b)}$$ $$=8(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$$

**Method 2**

Apply Jensens inequality to $$f(x)=\log \left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! But just for clarification , Will we get correct answer when we divide two inequalities? @Albus Dumbledore

Comment: @InfinityLies no your method is not correct if num<=a and denom<=b then num/denom need not be <=a/b

Comment: Ok understood . Thnx for the help again.

Comment: Really Nice. +1

Answer (score 1):

Although I am in favour of Albus' answer, here is another way to calculate the minimum directly using standard inequalities:

\begin{eqnarray*}\prod_{cyc}\frac{1+a}{1-a}
& \stackrel{GM-HM}{\geq} & \left(\frac{3}{\sum_{cyc}\frac{1-a}{1+a}}\right)^3\\
& = & \left(\frac{3}{3-2\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{1+a}}\right)^3\\
& \stackrel{\frac 1{1+x}\, concave}{\geq} & \left(\frac{3}{3-2\frac{1}{1+\sum_{cyc}a^2}}\right)^3\\
& \stackrel{Cauchy-Schwarz}{\geq} & \left(\frac{3}{3-\frac{2}{1+\frac 13}}\right)^3\\
& = & 2^3 = 8
\end{eqnarray*}

All inequalities are "sharp" for $a=b=c=\frac 13$.