# $a+b+c=1$, prove $(1+a)(1+b)(1+c) \ge 8(1-a)(1-b)(1-c) $, without AM-GM

Tags: inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

$a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$, if $a+b+c=1$, prove that
$$ (1+a)(1+b)(1+c) \ge 8(1-a)(1-b)(1-c) $$

but without AM-GM as the only tool.

---

**Collecting data:**

Since $a+b+c=1$, we cannot have one of the variable to be greater than or equal to 1. So
$$ \boxed{0 < a,b,c < 1} $$
Also by AM-GM: $1=a+b+c \ge 3(abc)^{1/3}$, or

$$ \boxed{abc \le \frac{1}{27}} $$

Next,
$$ (1-a)(1-b)(1-c) = [1 - (a+b) + ab](1-c) = \boxed{ 1 - (a+b+c) + (ab + ac + bc) - abc }$$
$$ =\boxed{ (ab+ac+bc)-abc} $$

Next,
$$ (1+a)(1+b)(1+c) = [1 + (a+b) + ab](1+c)  = 1 + (a+b+c) + (ac+ab+bc) + abc$$
$$ = \boxed{2 + (ac+bc+bc) + abc} $$

so the inequality is equivalent with:

$$ 2 + ac+bc+ab + abc \ge 8(ab+ac+bc) - 8abc $$
or

$$ \boxed{ 2 + 9abc \ge 7 (ab+ac+bc) } \:\: \leftarrow \:\: \text{to be proven} $$

Next, $(a+b+c)^{2} = a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2} + 2(ab+ac+bc) = 1$,
$$ \boxed{ab+ac+bc = \frac{1- (a^{2} + b^{2}+ c^{2})}{2}} $$

which means
$$ 7(ab+ac+bc) = \frac{7}{2} -\frac{7}{2}(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}) = 2 + \frac{3 - 7(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2})}{2}$$

and it is left to prove

$$ \frac{3-7(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2})}{2} \le 9abc $$

$$ \boxed{3  \le 18 abc  + 7(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2})} \:\: \leftarrow \:\: \text{to be proven}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
As an alternative, note $x \mapsto \log\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}$ is convex, and use [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality).

Comment: maybe you mean $f(x) = \log ( \frac{1-x}{1+x} )$, it is also convex. Then we hope Jensens can show $ \log ( \frac{1-a}{1+a} ) \le \frac{1}{2}$ also for $b,c$.

Comment: But how can we use it? involves $t=a, \: 1-t = b+c$?

Comment: Read up on Jensen's inequality from the link provided or any other source.  Using Jensen's inequality, if $f$ is convex, then $f(a)+f(b)+f(c) \geqslant 3\cdot f\left(\frac{a+b+c}3\right)$.  That gives you the answer directly.

Comment: That is not what I read in wiki, ok thanks.

Comment: Refer to the simplest "Finite Form" section - there is also an e.g. given where AM-GM is proved using Jensen.  There are a lot of resources on this inequality, including online ones like https://brilliant.org/wiki/jensens-inequality/

Comment: The $a+b+c=1$ does not really matter for Jensen's right?

Comment: It's used only when calculating $f\left(\dfrac{a+b+c}3\right)=f(\frac13)$… which is after the Jensen application.

Answer (score 3):

> $a+b+c=1.$ Prove that $(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)\geq 8(1-a)(1-b)(1-c).$

ETS) $(2a+b+c)(a+2b+c)(a+b+2c) \geq 8(a+b)(b+c)(c+a).$

Let $b+c=x, c+a=y, a+b=z.$

$\Leftrightarrow (x+y)(y+z)(z+x) \geq 8xyz.$

You may try from here.

Hint: $(x+y)^2\geq4xy.$

Comment: I know this solution. But what if without AM-GM only?

Comment: I didn't use any AM-GM for this. $(x+y)^2 \geq 4xy$ can be induced by $(x-y)^2\geq0.$

Comment: If you don't like this solution, try to solve this with Muirhead inequality by multiplying this out.

Comment: But it can be considered as AM-GM. Thanks for the answer +1, but I am looking for other solutions.

Comment: Or, such a famous solution, with Jensen inequality. Set $f(x)=\ln \frac {1+x}{1-x},$ then try to use Jensen inequality.

Comment: Same solution here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/425145/42969.

Answer (score 1):

*Proceeding along the OP*:

It suffices to prove that
$$2 + 9abc \ge 7(ab + bc + ca).$$

Degree three Schur inequality yields
$$(a + b + c)^3 - 4(a + b + c)(ab + bc + ca) + 9abc \ge 0$$
that is
$$1 - 4 (ab + bc + ca) + 9abc \ge 0.$$

It suffices to prove that
$$2 + 4(ab + bc + ca) - 1 \ge 7(ab + bc + ca)$$
or
$$1 \ge 3(ab + bc + ca)$$
which is true since $(a + b + c)^2 - 3(ab + bc + ca) = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - ab - bc - ca$ $= \frac12[(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2 + (c-a)^2]\ge 0$.

We are done.